# Request params changed when I pass it in Retrofit with HashMap in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I am using api call of retrofit and I want to pass JSONArray in Request params.

```
var requestMap: HashMap<String, Any> = hashMapOf("selected_conference_call_phone" to (getArrayOfSelectedPhones(addressItem.selectedConferenceCallPhone) as JSONArray))



private fun getArrayOfSelectedPhones(conferenceCallPhoneNumbers: ArrayList<SelectedConferenceCallNumberModel>): Any {

    var phoneJsonArray = JSONArray()
    try {

        for (i in 0 until conferenceCallPhoneNumbers.size) {
            var phoneJsonObject = JSONObject()
            phoneJsonObject.put("phone", conferenceCallPhoneNumbers[i].phone)
            phoneJsonArray.put(phoneJsonObject)
        }


    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }

    Timber.e("phoneNumberArray =====> $phoneJsonArray")

    return phoneJsonArray

}
// api call
val request = activityApi.save(
                authorization = prefs().getString(Constants.prefsKeys.TOKEN, "")
                        ?: "", body = requestMap)
        request.enqueue(object : Callback<ActivitySave> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ActivitySave>, response: Response<ActivitySave>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    hideProgress()
                    val activitySave = response.body()
                    if (activitySave != null) {
                        if (activitySave.flag) {
                            hideProgress()
                            greenToast(activitySave.message)
                            callback()
                        } else {
                            hideProgress()
                            Timber.e(activitySave.message)
                            redToast(activitySave.message)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    hideProgress()
                    Timber.e("${response.code()}: ${response.message()}")
                    redToast("${response.code()}: ${response.message()}")
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ActivitySave>, throwable: Throwable) {
                hideProgress()
                Timber.e(throwable.message ?: "")
                redToast(getString(R.string.server_unreachable))
            }
        })
    } else {
        hideProgress()
        Timber.e(getString(R.string.network_not_available))
        redToast(getString(R.string.network_not_available))
    }
}
```

=====================================================

Retrofit function

```
val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(WebConstants.BASE_URL)
        .client(OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                        .apply {
                            level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                            else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
                        }).build())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
```

================================================

dependency library used:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
```

when I check the request then it is displaying

```
  "selected_conference_call_phone": {
"values": [
  {
    "nameValuePairs": {
      "phone": "7897897878789"
    }
  },
  {
    "nameValuePairs": {
      "phone": "1234567890123"
    }
  }
]
}
```

instead of

```
[
  {
    "phone": "7897897878789"
  },
  {
    "phone": "1234567890123"
  }
]
```

What is the reason that this params is changed ?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that JSONArray and JSONObject are from Gson? I can't find the put method for this classes in Gson documentation